# if condition in complexity O(n * log(n))

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

```
s=0

for(i=1; i<n; i = i*2){ 
  if (i<20)
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        s=s+i*j;
    }
    s=s+1
}
```

I'm trying to establish the big-o complexity for the above algorithm. The outer loop starts at **1** and runs to **n**, counter in **i** doubles for each iteration, thus this is a **log(n)** behaviour. The inner loop runs independently from **0** to **n** with **O(n)** behaviour.?

I don't understand how **if** statement affects complexity. You might not want to provide me with the answer but please guide in the right direction as I don't get it at all.

Comment: Both algorithms are identical; did you paste the wrong code for one of them? In any case, the `if` statement doesn't affect the complexity, because it only removes a constant number of iterations of the outer loop.

Comment: @chepner Ok thank you, in this case the answer will be O(n * log(n))?

Comment: This is O(∞) since `i` in the outer loop will never be anything but 0.

Comment: @Sani Singh Huttunen Yeah. But I guess that's a typo as the op says `i` starts at 1...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner loop is `O(N)` but it will only run 5 times, 
i.e. when `i = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16`

After the first 5 iterations, your code basically becomes

```
for(i=32; i<n; i = i*2){ 
    s=s+1
}
```

which is `O(log(N))`

So the total complexity is:

```
O(5 * N + log(N)) = O(N)
```

Comment: Thank you. You were really helpful and passion today. Can you please tell me then if I had if condition if ((i < 10) || (i > n)) will this still be O(log(n))?

Comment: @AlinaKhachatrian it will still be O(N) -- same reason as my answer here: `i > n` will never happen because you have `i < n` in the for-loop condition, and `i < 10` or `i < 20` makes no differences when N gets to infinity